# Странное поведение функции str_replace

Tags: php

Есть строка вида

> некоторый текст кириллицей 912 12x150, некоторый текст кириллицей А4-70

По регулярному выражению я достаю из нее все числа и получаю массив вида (запятая в конце некоторых значений роли не играет)

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "912"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "150,"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "70"
}
```

После я преобразую эти числа в вещественный формат с 3 символами после запятой. Преобразованный массив выглядит вот так:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "912.000"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "12.000"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "150.000"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "4.000"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "70.000"
}
```

Затем я вызываю функцию

```
str_replace($arRawSize, $arSize, $sortable)
```

где $sortable - моя изначальная строка, $arRawSize - исходный массив, $arSize - преобразовнный массив.

На выходе получается что-то странное. Конкретно с верхней строкой результат вот такой:

> некоторый текст кириллицей 912.000.000 12.000x150.000 Некоторый текст кириллицей А4.000-70.000

Проблема в "912.000.000".

На другой строке

> некоторый текст кириллицей 912 18x70, некоторый текст кириллицей А4-70

Я получаю следующий результат

> некоторый текст кириллицей 912.000 18.000x70.000.000 некоторый текст кириллицей А4.000-70.000

Здесь с числом 912 все хорошо, а вот "70.000.000" - не то что ожидалось.

Есть и другие кейсы, в т.ч. и нормально замененные строки.

Пример правильной строки.

> некоторый текст кириллицей 912 8x35, некоторый текст кириллицей А4-70

На выходе получаем

> некоторый текст кириллицей 912.000 8.000x35.000 некоторый текст кириллицей А4.000-70.000

Что, в принципе, и ожидалось.

Это баг или фича? Возможно, я что-то упустил?

upd: PHP версии 7.2.34

Comment: А что мешает той же регуляркой проводить замену? `preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '$0.000', $sortable);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что одна строка является подстрокой другой, как следствие происходит замена в уже изменённых данных.

Например есть число 912 и 12, которые заменяются на 912.000 и 12.000 соответсвенно, но проблема в том, что сначала происходит замена на 912.000, а потом в нём уже 12 заменяется на 12.000 что в результате даёт 912.000.000.

Comment: Звучит логично. И во втором кейсе тоже дважды по 70. А в третьем повторений нет. Спасибо!